# why mean=50 instead of 0 and why is it even needed in this rnorm function? (From ISL book)

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mean

I'm new to the field of data science and I've started off by going through the Introduction to Statistical Learning book.

In there I am going through the introduction to R section and have come across the following:

```
x=rnorm(50)
y=x+rnorm(50,mean=50,sd=.1)
cor(x,y)
```

I understand that `x` and `y`, being vectors of size 50, have a very close correlation (about 99.5%) due to y just being a small shift in `x` of standard deviation 0.1.

However I do not understand why, for `y`, the mean is explicitly set to 50?

Should the mean not be 0 like it is for `x` (by default)?

From what I can see the values within the `y` matrix are also within the range of -2 and 2, giving a mean of roughly 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be $50$ and I think it is unfortunate that it is equal to the vector dimensions. Whatever it is, the correlation will be high because the mean shift of a RV doesn't affect it, i.e. $\operatorname{cor}(X+\mu,Y)=\operatorname{cor}(X,Y)$. The $y$ vector should have values distributed around $50$ by the way, not around $-2,2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also just re-ran all my code and now I am seeing the y values distributed around 50. Strange! Something I should watch out for in the future (I am writing in the RStudio notebook).